# "Can't find API database; API check was not performed" in Android App SDK with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, api, sdk

I'm starting a new Android App using the Android SDK on Eclipse, build tools 19.0.2, on a Windows 7 PC. At some point during my work, I started receiving the error "Can't find API database; API check was not performed". This error is not shown in the code but instead shows a red X in the project folder and a line one error in the Problems window. There is a previous question on this topic but that did not work for me. I have already tried adjusting the target and minimum SDK versions in the manifest and re-installed the SDK multiple times. This problem also occurs with the only other project in my work space and shows the same error. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This happened to me when I moved my sdk.

Answer (score 22):

For me, **Eclipse --> Project --> Clean...** is enough set everything right again:
[image]

Comment: BTW, what could be the reason for such a problem?

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal basically buggy dev tools, there's not much we can do about

Answer (score 11):

Following works for me:

1. Make sure you installed SDKs listed in your `manifest.xml`, i.e. mini version and target version.
2. Click the icon with red `x` on the right hand side tool bar, which has tip of 'Problems(...)' if you move your cursor over it.
3. Right click on your error, choose `quick fix`.
4. Choose `Disable Check in This Project`

Comment: BTW, what could be the reason for such a problem?